# Access angular controller from directive using require

Tags: angularjs

In a directive i want to require a controller but i get the error that the controller can't be found. I am sure it is a small thing or maybe it is not possible the way i want to do it.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
  
  //some function here returning data
}]);

angular.module('myApp').directive('yoloswag', function() {
  return {
    require: ['^?ngModel', '^GreetingController'],
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
      
      var modelCtrl = controllers[0],
          greetingsCtrl = controllers[1];
      
      console.log(controllers)
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    {{ greeting }}
    <div yoloswag>test</div>
</div>
  
</div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not having and dependency with your main module, that's why you are getting that error.

Your code should be the following

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';

  //some function here returning data
}])
.directive('yoloswag', function() {
  return {
    require: ['^?ngModel', '^GreetingController'],
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

      var modelCtrl = controllers[0],
          greetingsCtrl = controllers[1];

      console.log(controllers)
    }
  };
});
```

or set a variable for main module then you can add controller and directive with the main module like,

```
 var MainModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

    MainModule.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';

      //some function here returning data
    }]);
    MainModule.directive('yoloswag', function() {
      return {
        require: ['^?ngModel', '^GreetingController'],
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

          var modelCtrl = controllers[0],
              greetingsCtrl = controllers[1];

          console.log(controllers)
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: Hi Ramesh R, thank you for your reaction. After changing the code the error is still the same. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpYyjV?editors=1111

Comment: did you refer(import) your js file into your HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `controller` property of directive :

make sure don't update property in link function.

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    },
    controller : 'GreetingController',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var modelCtrl = controllers[0],
          greetingsCtrl = controllers[1];

      console.log(controllers)
    }
  };
```